# ExtJs MVC put a button handler inside a controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, dom-events, extjs-mvc

Is there any way in ExtJs MVC to put a button handler inside a controller, something like this:

```
this.control({
    'storage_settings button[action=submit_settings]': {
     handler: this.submit_settings_handler
  })
```

Or do I have to use something else like a `click` event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your code does define the button to listen to (`storage_settings button[action=submit_settings]`) but not the event to listen to (unless there's an event called `handler`, which there isn't).

`handler` is a config option you can give if your'e not using MVC (thus the handler will be within the view code). Since you are using MVC, you should listen to the `click` event. So:

```
this.control({
    'storage_settings button[action=submit_settings]': {
         click: this.submit_settings_handler
});
```

This should also work:

```
this.control({
    'storage_settings button[action=submit_settings]': {
         click: function( aButton, aEvent, aOptions )
         {
         }
});
```